# Calculate multiple number of date differences based on another variable in R

Tags: r

I have a df:

```
A <- c("1-23", "1-23", "1-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23", "10-23")
B <- c("2013-01-02", "2013-01-17", "2013-01-31", "2014-08-04", "2014-08-25", "2014-09-02", "2014-09-08", "2014-09-30", "2014-09-15")
df <- data.frame(A,B)
```

My current code is:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(A) %>%
mutate(days = difftime(B, lag(B), units = "days"))
```

The output I am getting is

```
   A      B           C
1   1-23  2013-01-02  NA
2   1-23  2013-01-17  15
3   1-23  2013-01-31  14
4   10-23 2014-08-04  NA
5   10-23 2014-08-25  21
6   10-23 2014-09-02  8
7   10-23 2014-09-08  6
8   10-23 2014-09-30  22
9   10-23 2014-09-15  -15
```

I DO NOT want this output for column C. I would like to know the difference in days for column B row 1 - row 1, row 1 - row 2, row 1 - row 3; column B row 4 - row 4, row 4 - row 5, row 4 - row 6 and so on and so forth. For column C the values should be

```
C <- c(0, 15, 29, 0, 21, 29, 35, 57, 42)
```

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(B = as.Date(B),
         C = B - first(B))
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   A [2]
  A     B          C      
  <chr> <date>     <drtn> 
1 1-23  2013-01-02  0 days
2 1-23  2013-01-17 15 days
3 1-23  2013-01-31 29 days
4 10-23 2014-08-04  0 days
5 10-23 2014-08-25 21 days
6 10-23 2014-09-02 29 days
7 10-23 2014-09-08 35 days
8 10-23 2014-09-30 57 days
9 10-23 2014-09-15 42 days
```